# How do I get my server to return the right Sec-WebSocket-Accept header value?

Tags: javascript, websocket

I seem to be getting the wrong hash value given the key through my webSocket. From what I can tell, the client side of the socket works, because when I have it connect to other servers, it's successful.

index.js

```
const http = require('http')
const cryp=require('crypto')
const port = 8080
var ourHTML=require('fs').readFile("index.html",(err,data) => {
        if(err) throw err;
        ourHTML = data.toString();
    });

const requestHandler = (request, response) => {
    //console.log(request)
    response.end(ourHTML)
}

const server = http.createServer(requestHandler)

server.on('upgrade',(req,socket)=>{
    if(req.headers['upgrade'] !== 'websocket'){
        socket.end('HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request');
        return;
    }
    const hash=getAVal(req.headers['sec-websocket-key']);
    console.log(hash);
    socket.write([
        "HTTP/1.1 101 Web Socket Protocol Handshake",
        "Upgrade: WebSocket",
        "Connection: Upgrade",
        `Sec-WebSocket-Accept: ${hash}`
    ].join('\r\n')+'\r\n\r\n');
    //socket.end();
});

function getAVal(key){
    console.log(key);
    return cryp
    .createHash('sha1')
    .update(key+'258EAFA5-E914–47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11', 'binary')
    .digest('base64');
}

server.listen(port, (err) => {
    if(err){
        return console.log("Uhh ohh,  "+err.stack,err)
    }
    console.log("server listening at "+port)
})
```

index.html

```
<html>
<head><title>Local Server</title></head>
<body><h1>Local Server Body</h1><p id="p">To Change</p></body>

<script>
console.log("here");
var ws=new WebSocket("ws://10.0.0.150:8080");
//var ws=new WebSocket("wss://echo.websocket.org");
setInterval(req,1000);

function req(){
    ws.send("tickReq");
}

ws.addEventListener('open', () => {
    ws.send("Hello");
});

ws.addEventListener('message', event => {
    document.getElementById("p").innerHTML=event.data;
});

</script>

</html>
```

An example for a key and hash pair when running is:

PxsrStN1CGLK/JBYydUFjg==

QAK+TE6u+sV705GI+LpP4yKM04Y=

The top is the key given by the browser, and the bottom is what the getAVal function is returning, and it being incorrect causing this message.

Error during WebSocket handshake: Incorrect 'Sec-WebSocket-Accept' header value

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the base64 string

```
"QAK+TE6u+sV705GI+LpP4yKM04Y="
```

decodes to bytes

```
4002BE4C4EAEFAC57BD39188F8BA4FE3228CD386
```

However, the correct SHA1 hash for the string

```
"PxsrStN1CGLK/JBYydUFjg==258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11"
```

is bytes

```
2FEA5BE3299C27C3DD290853435C7529BBBC0F0F
```

and the base64 encoded form of those bytes is

```
"L+pb4ymcJ8PdKQhTQ1x1Kbu8Dw8="
```

Which means your SHA1 hash is wrong to begin with.

Try calling `digest()` without an `encoding` specified so you can get a `Buffer` instead of a `string`, and then verify it matches the bytes above.

Then convert those bytes to base64 using `Buffer.toString("base64")` and verify it matches the string above.